# How to storing critical data in flutter?

Tags: flutter

As the info of Shared_preferences packages in `flutter`.

`Wraps NSUserDefaults (on iOS) and SharedPreferences (on Android), providing a persistent store for simple data. Data is persisted to disk asynchronously. Neither platform can guarantee that writes will be persisted to disk after returning and this plugin must not be used for storing critical data.`

What is the right way I can store my critical data?

an example is access token

Comment: You can use either a file, a local SQLite database or a remote one. [Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5965747-data-persistence-on-flutter).

Comment: use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Comment: if I use file or sqlite to store data, can other app get that data? or only my app can connect to it ? @tomerpacific

Comment: @Hamed are you have any experience about flutter_secure_storage

Comment: @MinhTrần yes, I used this package in one of my projects.

Comment: @MinhTrần - Depending on what you choose, your application should be the only one able to connect/access the files. Obviously, each method has it's limitations in respect to security.

Comment: Thank you! I will research more about flutter_secure_storage and save data with local file or sqlite :D

Answer (score 1):

Use get storage package is best for you
https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage
Here is link of this package